# Lightning Flow from Contact List View

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, visual-workflow, list-view

I've created a flow with a screen. The desired outcome is for a user to select a few Contact records from a List view, feed them into a flow, which will prompt the user with a screen with a lookup field to select a User to become the new Owner of the selected Contacts.

Because lookups require the Lightning runtime environment for flows, I was trying to avoid using a VF page to feed in the records. I tried following this guide: https://www.xbaf.com/flow-list-buttons but I got an error of: "Lightning out App error in callback function - When calling a flow from a list view button" and my flow wouldn't execute.

I then tried this method (adapted for Contacts instead of Accounts): https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2019/03/29/how-to-pass-record-ids-from-list-view-to-a-flow-in-lightning/ and I can successfully pass the IDs to the Flow, but it runs in Classic runtime and the flow fails.

I found this article on how to force Lightning runtime for Flows called from a VF page, but I'm not sure how to adapt my page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_lightningruntime.htm

My VF page is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="Contacts" extensions="PassSelectedContactIdsToFlowVFController" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <!-- Runs your Flow -->   
    <flow:interview name="Update_Contact_Owner"
          finishLocation="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Tab, $ObjectType.Contact)}">
        <apex:param name="ids" value="selectedContactIds"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

and my controller is:

```
public class PassSelectedContactIdsToFlowVFController {

    public string[] selectedContactIds{get;set;}
    
    public passSelectedContactIdsToFlowVFController(ApexPages.StandardSetController listController){
        selectedContactIds = new string[]{};
        for(Contact c : (Contact[])listController.getSelected()){
            selectedContactIds.add(c.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adapting this page/controller/flow to pass in a collection of Contact records rather than IDs to better handle bulkification, but I got a different error saying the flow couldn't translate the data types or something similar. That's probably a different question though.

Comment: I've gotten the bigassforce method working in both classic and lightning.  I do recall seeing that issue and finding a fix for it.  Can't remember the details.  I'll see if I can figure it out again, but definitely poke on it.  It did work as of say 6 months ago, though of course things do often change in flow and lightning...